# How to eliminate org/apache/jsp from the output path of the Apache Sling jspc-maven-plugin?

Tags: maven

I am trying to use the [jspc-maven-plugin](http://leonardehrenfried.github.io/jspc-maven-plugin/compile-mojo.html) from Apache Sling.  When I compile my JSPs, they end up in my `target/org/apache/jsp` directory.  I want them to go go directly under `target` or under `target/classes` w/o the `org/apache/jsp` part.  How can I achieve this?  Here is my plugin specification:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.sling</groupId>
    <artifactId>jspc-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>compile-jsp</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>jspc</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <sourceDirectory>${basedir}/source/html</sourceDirectory>
          <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target</outputDirectory>
          <includes>
            <include>**/*.jsp</include>
          </includes>
          <showSuccess>true</showSuccess>
          <failOnError>false</failOnError>
          <compilerSourceVM>${javac.source}</compilerSourceVM>
          <compilerTargetVM>${javac.target}</compilerTargetVM>
          <servletPackage/> <!-- doesn't seem to matter - deprecated -->
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Comment: Are those classes in the package named `org.apache.jsp`?

Comment: Yes, they get put there.